# PDF Merge of pdfs with differing page size

Tags: pdf, pdfpages

Can a single PDF file, which is the result of a merge, contain pages of different sizes, e.g. A4 and Letter? If so, can you point me to merge tools that preserve page size?

Comment: This is not related to TeX and friends. It's best you asked this elsewhere, e.g. http://superuser.com/

Comment: @CountZero: I do not see a reason for closing. The question is tagged with {pdfpages}, And with package `pdfpages` the question can be answered.

Answer (score 16):

Yes, PDF files can have pages with different page sizes (media sizes).

Yes, package `pdfpages` is able to "merge" PDF file with different page sizes and preserve them in the output, if option `fitpaper` is given, e.g.:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=-,fitpaper]{document-a4}
\includepdf[pages=-,fitpaper]{document-letter}
\end{document}
```

Option `fitpaper` has a limitation that it assumes that the pages of the included PDF have the same media size.

Comment: +1 Thanks. If I call `\includepdf{pages=1-last]{1.pdf}` and `\includepdf{pages=1-last]{2.pdf}`, what is the page size of the output pdf file? Is it the same as the page size of `1.pdf` or of `2.pdf`?

Comment: A different question: Can `pdfpages` or some LaTeX package remove OCRed text from a pdf file? See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171940/how-can-i-convert-a-scanned-pdf-with-ocred-text-to-one-without-ocred-text

Comment: @Tim Without option `fitpaper`, the page size is the page size of the including document.

Comment: My question was: the page sizes of 1.pdf and 2.pdf (viewed under 100% zoom level) are different, but the pdflatex generated combined  pdf file will have the same page size for all pages.

Comment: @Tim As I said, the page size of the including document.

Comment: I combine two pdf files into one using the same LaTEX code as in your post but without `fitpaper`. The page sizes for the two input pdf files are different. So what is "the page size of the including document"?

Comment: @Tim The *including* document is the document that includes the two files `1.pdf` and `2.pdf`. The latter would be *included* documents.

Comment: I see. What is the page size of the including document?

Comment: @Tim It depends on the class, options, packages. The standard classes (`article`, `report`, `book`) are using letter as default paper size. But this can be overwritten by options (`a4paper`, ...), packages like `geometry` or manual settings of `\paperwidth` and `\paperheight`.

Answer (score -1):

`pdfpages` uses `includegraphics` under the hood, so you can just do something like

```
\includegraphics[width=6in, height=9.25in, keepaspectratio]{back.pdf}
\includegraphics[width=0.541in, height=9.25in, keepaspectratio]{spine.pdf}
\includegraphics[width=6in, height=9.25in, keepaspectratio]{cover.pdf}
```

or however you would like to organize your pdfs

Comment: You do not answer the question: Can a PDF file have pages with different page sizes?

Comment: When I stumbled across this question I interpreted it a bit differently, and I was wondering if I could include PDFs of different sizes on the same page in the PDF. It’s not the same as the top answer but I think it can help others who have a slightly varied question. 

For the record I ended up using Adobe Acrobat for merging PDF files since pdfpages would still force the output PDF to have all the same page size.